# Can I use the matrix of the object detected from Raycaster to calculate its vector in the face I intersected with? If so, how do I do it?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to calculate the angle between my direction of displacement and the wall(which is a THREE.Mesh), but I have no idea how to find the vector of the wall. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: It's usually most helpful to post some of the code you've tried already that is giving you problems.

Comment: if you can get the wall from a raycast you can get the intersected face - faces have normal and normal is the vector you are searching for